# Core data calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm making a calendar app with core data, and trying to mark each day if that date has any events (month view).

I could fetch all objects in the date range, check if each date has any events, but if there's many, this seams rather inefficient, and memory consuming.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate, endDate];
```

Is there a better way to check if a range of dates has events associated with them?

Thanks

Comment: So you're storing dates in the data store and not events? And each date may or may not have events?

Comment: I store events, and each event has a due date associated... So each date in the calendar might or might not have an event

Comment: You could create a separate entity that contains just the dates that do have events data (indexed). You could also store an event count for that day.

Comment: So what is your predicate operating on? It should be filtering events to get only the ones for the dates you need...

Comment: What do you consider "many"?

Comment: Without seeing your model it's hard to say but if I was in your position I'd have a date<-->>event relationship going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate is very efficient. It should work fine with 100.000+ events. Index the date attribute for even better performance.